# .includes() on part of an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

So I have an object of goals. And I wanna see if one specific goal is inside.

I'm doing this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.goalsHome.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.goalsHome[i].includes(goal));
}
```

Which results in an error includes does not exists on type object.

But what If I want to check one specific object property ? Let's say I want to check if the goal's comment matches one of the goals comment in the object. That should be possible right ? By looping trough it?

[image: image with the object]

But if I add `.comment` in between it says comment doesn't exist on type object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using stringify.

```
let goalFound = false;
let goalsSide;

    if (side == 'home') {
        goalsSide = this.goalsHome;
    } else {
        goalsSide = this.goalsAway;
    }

for (let i = 0; i < goalsSide.length; i++) {
            let stringGoals = JSON.stringify(goalsSide[i]);
            let stringGoal = JSON.stringify(goal);

            if (stringGoals == stringGoal) {
                goalFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (goalFound != true) {
            this.addGoalToArray(goal, side);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to check if there is an object in the array with a comment matching the goals comment. If this is what you want to do you can do

```
this.goalsHome.filter(goalHome => goalHome.comment === goal.comment);
```

If you want to look for all matching objects. (See [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

If you want to know whether a single match exists you can use the `Array.prototype.some()` method like so;

```
this.goalsHome.some(goalHome => goalHome.comment === goal.comment);
```

which will return true if there is atleast one match in the array (See [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)).

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either. I get this error:
Property 'comment' does not exist on type 'object'. :(